# Abbreviating a URL using IIS6

Tags: iis-6

Our web server is running IIS 6.0 and I have set up an abbreviated URL which points at the IP address of the web server. IIS is configured to bring up a web page located in a certain directory when a request comes in via the abbreviated URL. The problem that I am trying to resolve is, how do I configure IIS so that when requests come in via the abbreviated URL, it is the abbreviated URL that is displayed in the browsers address line instead of the 'Full' URL, which I do not want the user to see?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up host header recognition - go to the IIS management MMC, Web Sites > Right click on the site you want to add the short URL to, on the Web Site tab click "Advanced", Click "Add" and set the TCP port to 80 and the Host Header Value to the short URL.

To make sure I understand what you're asking, when you say "I have set up an abbreviated URL" do you mean an alias in DNS, right?